# Conditional product attributes Nopcommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I need to add conditional product attributes to a existing Nopcommerce webshop. I've had a lot of headache the last days to think of a good solution. After googling for a while it seems that this function is scheduled for a later release.

http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/workitem/11008

What is the best solution to add this functionality?

NopCommerce V3.20 is being used.

Comment: Hi, how did you go about doing this? I have a similar requirement.